# SQL : group by on values

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table A with column named DIF. This column can have 4 distinct values (a - b - c - d).

I would to group by results on this DIF column

```
select count(*) from table A group by DIF;
```

But for values c et d, I would like them to be together. So I would have the count(*) for a, for b and for cd.

How is it possible ?

Comment: You want [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/DPz5NNlf)?

Comment: [CASE Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html): *`CASE` expressions let you use `IF ... THEN ... ELSE` logic in SQL statements without having to invoke procedures*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN dif IN ('c', 'd') THEN 'cd' ELSE dif END AS dif,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       CASE WHEN dif IN ('c', 'd') THEN 'cd' ELSE dif END;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dif) AS
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'd' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Outputs:

| DIF | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| b | 3 |
| a | 5 |
| cd | 13 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QJut-M2t)

Answer (score 0):

**Case** should do the trick

```
select col5,count(*) from TABLE1_ GROUP BY col5
```

Returns
[image: place holder data as an example]

using **Case** to define a new variable to group by like so :

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN col5 IN ('brown', 'green') THEN 'browngreen'
    ELSE col5
  END AS GroupedDIF,
  COUNT(*) AS Count_
FROM TABLE1_
GROUP BY GroupedDIF;
```

Returns

[image: final picture with answer]

Note: This is done with postgresql not oracle but should be understandable

Comment: This is not valid syntax in Oracle; you will get the exception `ORA-00904: "GROUPEDDIF": invalid identifier` as the `GROUP BY` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause so you cannot use the column alias.